# Parent RecyclerView picks up gestures that were intended to be for the nested RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, carousel, horizontal-scrolling

I have a vertical `RecyclerView` and a nested horizontal `RecyclerView` as one of its children. The inner view is used as an image carousel with a `PagerSnapHelper`. I'm getting a less than ideal behavior when I try to scroll the inner view horizontally. Sometimes, the parent view picks up the gesture and scrolls vertically even though my intention was to scroll the inner view horizontally. Is there a way to configure the default scroll detector such that horizontal scrolling is smoother?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you try using this `RecyclerView` with `overriden method` as a parent `RecyclerView`:

```
public class CustomRecyclerView extends RecyclerView {

    private int mTouchSlop;
    private float mPrevX;

    public CustomRecyclerView(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        mTouchSlop = ViewConfiguration.get(context).getScaledTouchSlop();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
        switch (e.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                mPrevX = MotionEvent.obtain(e).getX();
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                final float eventX = e.getX();
                float xDiff = Math.abs(eventX - mPrevX);

                if (xDiff > mTouchSlop) {
                    return false;
                }
        }

        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(e);
    }
}
```

example in xml

```
<com.example.stackoverflow.CustomRecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Comment: Thanks for this great snippet! Can you explain why you called the `obtain` function instead of doing `e.getX()`?

Comment: The snippet is not mine... I found it  from my old code where i had issue with webview,inside swiperefreshLayout. I did setup sample project and implemented your scenario to see if it would work with RecyclerView - it kinda did. Did it work for you? I will post link to original answer if i find it.

Comment: I'm still testing, and I can't tell if it's working or not. One thing I noticed is the nested `RecyclerView` picks up gestures only if the parent scroll state is idle. On iOS, this is more natural (i.e. the nested child can pick up gestures while the parent is still scrolling). Do you know how to change the Android behavior?

Comment: No i don't know. And i believe it's not possible - haven't seen any app on android that could do that, even google's youTube(which i assume was developed natively).

Answer (score 1):

below approach is trying to disable touch events for parent recyclerview when touching to nested recyclerview.

```
    nestedRecyclerView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch (View v, MotionEvent event){
    int action = event.getAction();
    switch (action) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            // Disallow parent to intercept touch events.
            v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            // Allow parent to intercept touch events.
            v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
            break;
    }

    // Handle inner(child) touch events.
    v.onTouchEvent(event);
    return true;
}
});
```